# array.includes doesn't work when checking if an iterator exists in array

Tags: javascript

I'm encountering some unexpected behavior in my JavaScript code which I'd like to understand. I want a one-line function to detect if a number exists inside an array of integers. The number being checked is the iterator of a loop in another array. I'm using the standard `includes()` function, should note the same happens with an `indexOf() >= 0` check. For this test we have the following code:

```
const array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
const array2 = [1, 2];
for(let i in array1)
    console.log(array2.includes(i));
```

To my surprise each output returns `false` instead of the expected `false true true false` sequence. How can this be? I know I'm checking `i` not `arr[i]`, but `i` still corresponds to the numbers included in those arrays: 0 is still 0, 1 is still 1, etc. Using `arr.includes(1)` does return true, so why not `arr.includes(i)` when `i` is also 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `for...in` loops through all the keys/properties.

It is a string, not number, which comes from the bracket property accessor

```js
const array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
const array2 = [1, 2];
for(let i in array1)
    console.log(typeof i, i, array2.includes(i));
```

A `for...of` loops through the values if the object is an iterable, defined by some function that I don't know off the top of my head and isn't important right now.

```js
const array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
const array2 = [1, 2];
for(let i of array1)
    console.log(typeof i, i, array2.includes(i));
```

Also know that your `for...in` loop doesn't do what you seem to expect it to do when `array1` isn't an incrementing integer list starting at 0:

```js
const array1 = [6, 4, 3, 95, 45, 3, 3];
for(let i in array1)
    console.log(typeof i, i);
```

So what you should do is just use `for...of` (or `Array.prototype.forEach`, or a traditional `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` loop, etc.) unless you need a `for...in` (which is almost never), or in this case I guess you can cast the string to a number before checking if it's called on `Array.prototype.includes`

```js
const array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
const array2 = [1, 2];
for(let i in array1)
    console.log(i, array2.includes(parseInt(i)));
```

Comment: That explains it: I was confused what the difference is, if `i` is stored as a string that would explain it. This means using `Number(i)` should also work in theory.

Answer (score 1):

`for...in` loops through all properties, not values. Arrays are objects, and their properties are `0 ... array.length`, so `i` inside the `for` loop is `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`.

You should be using a `for...of` loop instead:

```js
const array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
const array2 = [1, 2];
for(let i of array1)
    console.log(array2.includes(i));
```

Comment: That seems to work, thanks. Seems other things in my code break if I use `of` instead of `in` so I might have to find another way still, but this is useful for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) with arrays and `for..in` with objects

> The for...of statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects,
> including: built-in String, Array, array-like objects (e.g., arguments
> or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables. It
> invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the
> value of each distinct property of the object. - MDN

```js
const array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
const array2 = [1, 2];
for (let i of array1) console.log(array2.includes(i));
```

**Alternate options**

You can also use forEach here to achieve the exact same result:

```js
const array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
const array2 = [1, 2];
array1.forEach((val) => console.log(array2.includes(val)));
```

Comment: That seems to work, thanks. Seems other things in my code break if I use `of` instead of `in` so I might have to find another way still, but this is useful for future reference.